# ajax request headers without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created the following JavaScript function to load images of a vehicle, or load the alternate image if it is not available. The problem is that this page is 1kb, meanwhile it has to load the entire jquery library at 85+kb just for this one function. So my question is, is there some way to accomplish the same without having to load the jQuery library?

```
function GetImages() {
var Query = location.search;
//If query exists
if ((Query != "") && (Query != "?")){
var chunks = Query.split("=");
//If passed the right parameter
if (chunks[0] == "?unit") {
    var Unit = chunks[1];
    for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
        var unitimageURL = "/pics/"+Unit+"-"+i+".png";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'HEAD',
            url: unitimageURL,
            async: false,

            success: function() {
                $('.pictures').append("<img src="+unitimageURL+" width=150 height=90 alt='Unit "+Unit+" Picture "+i+"'>&nbsp;");
                if ((i == 4) || (i ==8)) {
                $('.pictures').append("<br>");
                }

            },
            error: function() {

                $('.pictures').append("<img src=nopic2.png width=150 height=90 alt='Unit "+Unit+" Picture "+i+"'>&nbsp;");
                if ((i == 4) || (i ==8)) {
                $('.pictures').append("<br>");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
}
else {
alert("No query");
}
}
```

Comment: Use a jQuery cdn so you'll likely not have to download jQuery again

Comment: jQuery is only 30kb compressed (if you're not compressing your traffic then start). And as @Musa says, if you use a CDN such as http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js, your users will almost certainly already have it cached.

Comment: I've linked my jQuery library to the CDN you mentioned instead of loading it right from our servers. While it's still a larger chunk than I'd like I suppose you're right clients probably have it cached or would after the first page load  anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way - the good old `var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();` way!
Don't forget to to set all the needed callbacks, check response statuses and everything will be fine.
To create a HEAD request, just specify "HEAD" as parameter to `.open()` method.

You will also need `document.createElement()` to append the results to your page (or you may use `.innerHTML` property as well.

Also, documentation like this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_xmlhttprequest.htm may be handy.